# place the aliased version of an existing command in /usr/bin/

Tags: bash, vim, alias, executable, git

I use **Vim** a lot, and I know how I can [start vim in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11464088/939986). So I have an alias named `vii` in my `.bash_aliases` file.

On other hand I use **Git** a lot too, and I have this line in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    editor = vi
```

To write a commit message the vi editor is opened every time and I have to go in insert mode. So I thought of replacing `vi` with `vii`, and did.

But the problem is when I do `git commit`, instead of opening the vim in insert mode, it gives this error:

```
error: cannot run vii: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vii'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

This makes clear that git does not looks to `.bash_aliases` file, even it isn't related to bash in any way. It does directly looks if there is `/usr/bin/vii` or not. And executes it if it is.

#### The Question

Can I place the aliased version of vi as `vii` in `/usr/bin/`?

*(and please don't suggest me to use `git commit -m "<commit message>"`. There are other situation where I need vim in insert mode.)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aliases are internal to each of your current shell environments - they are *expanded* by the currently running shell (`bash` in your case), so they only have effect on what you execute by typing/pasting in your terminal.

You have at least two options here:

- create a **wrapper** script named `vii` that will execute `vim -c 'startinsert'` and put it preferably in `/usr/local/bin/` (or `$HOME/bin`, if it exists and is in your search path). The script only needs to contain

  ```
  #!/bin/sh1
  exec vim -c 'startinsert' "$@" 2
  ```

  (Make sure to make it executable by running `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vii`.) Depending on the `PATH` configuration of your `git`/other programs, you may need to specify full path to that wrapper script (i.e., `editor = /usr/local/bin/vii`).
- If it is ok for you to have vim always start in insert mode, configure it to do so by adding `startinsert` at the end of `.vimrc`.

---

<sup>1</sup>   You can write the "she-bang" line as `#!/bin/bash`, but there's no need to in a script that contains no `bash`isms.
<sup>2</sup>   `$@` must be in double quotes in case the script is ever called with argument(s) that contain space(s). `startinsert` does not need to be quoted (but it doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 6):

Just set the editor variable to

```
[core]
    editor = vim -c 'startinsert'
```

For your other answer, no, you can't place aliases in a directory, as an alias is a concept from your shell. The normal way is to create an appropriate wrapper script to execute the specified commands, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
vim -c 'startinsert' "$@"
```

and save the script as `vii` and make it executable. You can place the script wherever you like, but typically such scripts are saved in somewhere in your `$HOME` folder like `$HOME/bin` and not in the global directories.